# Which color is "transparent" for WinPhone (AppBar-Icons)?

Tags: c#, colors, windows-phone

For example, in XNA it´s some kind of pink. If the color has - for example - #123123, it is handled as transparent.

What is the Hexvalue for transparency in WindowsPhone ?

Comment: Isn't it the alpha that determines the transparency? ARGB instead of RGB

Comment: Alpha-channel not available. There has to be a certain "color" for transparency, like in XNA